# Django Rest Framework admin styling messed up

Tags: python, css, django, django-rest-framework

I recently noticed my Django admin styling is messed up. The CSS seems to be working though and everything works, but once you click on a model, the next page is messed up. Does anyone know what causes this? I don't remember changing anything that would cause this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar before, the fix for me was changing the DEBUG setting.